# Need help on understanding Writefile

Tags: arduino, serial-port, writefile

I would like your assistance to understand a bit of code that would hugely help me in my project. Without going into too much details, here is what is causing me so much problems :

```
    bool Serial::WriteData(char *buffer, unsigned int nbChar)
{
    DWORD bytesSend;

    //Try to write the buffer on the Serial port
    if(!WriteFile(this->hSerial, (void *)buffer, nbChar, &bytesSend, 0))
    {
        //In case it don't work get comm error and return false
        ClearCommError(this->hSerial, &this->errors, &this->status);

        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

I use this function to send a variable to my Arduino Uno over Serial port like this :

```
snprintf(Data, sizeof(Data) - 1, "%3.1f", (int)(pf->speedKmh)*1.0);
SP->WriteData(Data, sizeof(Data) - 1); printf("\nData\n");
```

Some helpful info :

- *speedkmh is a float*
- *char Data[8] = "";*

So my question is : I would like to know **exactly** what is being sent to the Arduino. At the moment I don't really know if it is sending an array, bits one at a time, if it sends a float etc... Could you help me understand this?

Thanks!

Comment: Surely you meant to use strlen(Data) instead of sizeof(Data).  Right now you are sending garbage bytes, whatever is beyond the string terminator.  Add logging if you need to know what is actually getting sent.  Albeit that it is unlikely to demonstrate the bug, a serial port spy utility is the better weapon of choice.

Answer (score 0):

The following line:
    snprintf(Data, sizeof(Data) - 1, "%3.1f", (int)(pf->speedKmh)*1.0);

converts your floating point number to a string (an array of characters). Then

```
SP->WriteData(Data, sizeof(Data) - 1); printf("\nData\n");
```

sends these characters, one at a time, over the serial port.

BTW, it is not very clear why you convert your float to an integer, then back to a float (by multiplying it by 1.0), then to a string. As I see it, this would have the result of truncating the fractional part of the float, then appending a misleading ".0" to the string (from the ".1f" part of the control string). That is, both 1.0 and 1.4 will be converted to "1.0".